# How much is an asset worth that produces a constant income?

Tags: value

Say you have an asset that produces for you £1k per year profit (adjusted for inflation) at a constant rate? (The proverbial immortal goose that lays golden eggs).

Logic would say it's potential is infinite.

But for an individual of age 30 it is only worth up to £50k in their lifetime. And they may care less about what happens to it after they die.

But to a company who buys it, companies can live essentially forever.

Answer (score 7):

An asset that gives you a constant sum of nominal income every year is called a [perpetuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuity). (The UK government used to issue such a product and called it a [consol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consol_(bond)).)

Everyone "knows" that £1,000 received next year is worth less than £1,000 received this year. But how much less?

To try to formalize this notion, economists use the concepts of **discount rate** and **present value**. The discount rate is the rate at which you discount future returns.

If for example your discount rate is $5\%$, then this means you treat £1,000 received next year as equivalent to £950 received this year. (And an economist would say that the present value of £1,000 received next year is £950.)

---

We can now answer your specific numerical question:

- For simplicity, suppose your discount rate is fixed as $\delta$.

Then the present value of this asset is: $$1000+(1 -\delta)1000+(1 -\delta)^21000+\dots = \frac{1000}{\delta}.$$

- More generally, suppose your discount rate each year is $\delta_t$ ($t=0,1,2,\dots$).

Then the present value of this asset is: $$1000+(1 -\delta_1)1000+(1 -\delta_1)(1 -\delta_2)1000+\dots.$$

---

The brief discussion above is usually covered in greater depth in a course on Intermediate Microeconomics. See e.g. [Varian](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393919676) (2014, 9e) Ch. 10.

Comment: Quibble: Your sentence "Everyone "knows" that £1,000 received this year is worth less than £1,000 received next year. But how much less?" should be "more" and "more" or swap "this" and "next".

Comment: And  non-quibble. Your formula should be 1000/delta, since you're raising (1-delta) to powers.

Comment: `Everyone "knows" that £1,000 received this year is worth less than £1,000 received next year.` Why? Money I get today I can invest today so it's worth more next year.

Comment: @JKreft and Mast: Now corrected.